# Create new columns based on folder names and put the number of files that are in that folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using this python code to get the number of files that are in a specific folder:

```
import fnmatch
import pandas as pd
df=pd.dataFrame()

path1 = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\A_folder\B_folder\IT\tasks"
file=len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path1), '*.xlsx'))

print(file)
Out []:
 10

path11 = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\A_folder\B_folder\IT\finished_tasks"
file=len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path11), '*.xlsx'))

print(file)
Out []:
 7

path2 = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\A_folder\B_folder\Finance\tasks"
file=len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path2), '*.xlsx'))

print(file)
Out []:
 13
path2 = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\A_folder\B_folder\Finance\finished_tasks"
file=len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path2), '*.xlsx'))

print(file)
Out []:
 9
```

I want to create a data frame that looks like this:

```
      Main_foder              tasks      finished_tasks
0        IT                     10             7
1        Finance                13             9
```

I was trying to create main folders based on conditions. I tried this one:

```
m1=path1.eq(df.loc[path1.str.rsplit("\\").str[-1] == 'task', 'path1'])
m2=path11.eq(df.loc[path11.str.rsplit("\\").str[-1] == 'finished_tasks', 'path11'])
```

then create columns with this:

```
df['task'] = np.where(m1, file1, "") 
df['finished_tasks'] = np.where(m2, file2, "")
```

But it didn't work. Do you have any idea how can I create a dataframe like I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be :

```
import pandas as pd
import fnmatch
import os
import glob 

folders = glob('r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\A_folder\B_folder\*')
df = pd.DataFrame()
main_folder = []
tasks = []
finished_tasks = []
for fold in folders:
    ind_path = fold.split('\\')
    path1 = fold + '\\tasks'
    path2 = fold + '\\finished_tasks'
    main_folder.append(ind_path[2])
    tasks.append(len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path1), '*.xlsx')))
    finished_tasks.append((fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path2), '*.xlsx')))

df['Main_Folder'] = df['Main_Folder'].append(pd.Series(main_folder))
df['tasks'] = df['tasks'].append(pd.Series(tasks))
df['finished_tasks'] = df['finished_tasks'].append(pd.Series(finished_tasks))
```